# Different unit for Kubernetes resource memory on pods

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-metrics

My question is related to Kubernetes and the units of the metrics used for the HPA (autoscaling).

When I run the command

`kubectl describe hpa my-autoscaler`

I get (a part of more information) this:

```
...
Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
  resource memory on pods:                             318067507200m / 1000Mi
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  1% (1m) / 80%
...
```

In this example, when you can see the metrics for the **resource memory on pods**, you can see that the unit for the `current` value is `m`, which is "millis" (as is described in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?core-object=true#term-quantity)), but the unit used for the `target` value is `Mi`, which is "Mebis"

Is there any problem with the usage of different units?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are just different multipliers. The actual code is using a raw number of bytes under the hood.